# SQL: checking duplicate to inner join table and move the duplicate records to another table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

My project was i need to check the duplicate on TABLE1, TABLE2 and the duplicate result should be insert to TABLE3.

I have a code here that have error.

> > **ERROR:** *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.*

```
Insert * into TABLE3 from TABLE2 where TABLE2.Column in (select TABLE2.Column from TABLE2 inner join TABLE1 on TABLE1.Column =TABLE2.Column)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for the Insert statement is incorrect. 
Here is the correct syntax:

```
Insert into TABLE3 select * from TABLE2 where TABLE2.Column in (select TABLE2.Column from TABLE2 inner join TABLE1 on TABLE1.Column =TABLE2.Column)
```

Comment: Yeah, I already figure it out when im done posting. Thanks bro.

Comment: @RomartDubluis . . . You can still accept this answer.